# discord-player: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm in the process of making a discord music bot using the discord-player library. When I try to start the bot I get the following error that points to the `discord-player` import line in `bot.js`:

I currently use discord.js v14.2.0

```
const { Player } = require("discord-player");
```

```
C:\Users\Darx\projects\haubot\node_modules\discord-player\dist\index.js:2095
  if (import_voice4.version.includes("-dev") || import_voice4.version.startsWith("1"))
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
    at C:\Users\Darx\projects\haubot\node_modules\discord-player\dist\index.js:2095:29
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Darx\projects\haubot\node_modules\discord-player\dist\index.js:2099:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Darx\projects\haubot\bot.js:9:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)

Node.js v18.6.0
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"@discordjs/builders": "^0.15.0",
"@discordjs/opus": "^0.8.0",
"@discordjs/rest": "^0.5.0",
"@discordjs/voice": "^0.10.0",
"discord-api-types": "^0.34.0",
"discord-player": "^6.1.0",
"discord.js": "^14.2.0",
"dotenv": "^16.0.1",
"ffmpeg-static": "^5.0.2",
"libsodium-wrappers": "^0.7.10",
"nodemon": "^2.0.19",
"yt-search": "^2.10.4",
"ytdl": "^1.4.1",
"ytdl-core": "^4.11.2"
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I wrote an issue about it here https://github.com/TannerGabriel/discord-bot/issues/215 .